# Xcode 6.3 doesn't show simulator of connected device version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a strange problem. I have an iPhone 6 which is on iOS 8.3 and I'm using Xcode 6.3. When my iPhone is not connected to Xcode, I can select the iPhone 6 simulator alright but when my device is connected, iPhone 6 disappears from the list. I wasn't able to test this with other devices since I only have an iPhone 6. Does this happen to everyone or is it just me? Is there a way to use the iPhone 6 simulator when my iPhone 6 is connected to the computer? Screenshots are below.

when connected:

[image: when connected]

when not connected:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you deleted the whole Xcode app and install it again? (it sounds weird)

Comment: No, and honestly, seems a bit overkill. I would appreciate an easier solution. Doesn't this happen to everyone?

Comment: It won't make a difference anyway.  Wiping out `~/Library/Developer` and/or `~/Library/Application Support/Developer` will have an effect, as that's where Xcode stores stuff.  However it looks like a bug to me, but a small one, given you know the solution if you want to use the iPhone 6 Simulator.

Comment: The thing is I can not use the iPhone 6 simulator when I'm charging my phone, which is a bit annoying at times

Comment: It is not a solution as it drains during the day.

Comment: There is no solution.  Your question is "does this happen to anyone else".  That is off topic and you haven't even told us which version of Xcode you are using.  I am voting to close.

Comment: I wrote the version of Xcode in the title, will add it to the question too. How do you know that there is no solution?

Comment: @trojanfoe He mentioned which version he is using 8.3.

Comment: Ah so you did, apologies. But as I said, it looks like a bug and there is nothing anyone can do here.

Comment: Can u try to delete everything in the CoreSimulator Folder? So "reset" your Simulator content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem vanished when I installed all the available simulators from Preferences > Downloads